# Centering a div within a responsive div

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Basically I have 3 floating elements, they are next to each other and are scaled down when you resize the browser window.
Now under a certain width (@media (max-width: 800px)) the elements get a fixed width and a clear:both so that they are below eachother and no longer scale.

What I'm trying to do now is centering those 3 divs inside their parent.

`margin:0 auto` is not helping

Above 800pixel width:
[image: Imgur]

Below 800pixel width:

[image: Imgur]

--> Div should be centered inside the yellow one

Code I have for the media query:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
.data .data_column{width:215px;background-color:red;clear:both; margin: 0 auto;}
.data{width:90%;background-color:yellow;}
```

}

Comment: Something else in your code is effecting it, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/xn0mnmrL/). Provide the mark up and more css?

Comment: Preferably provide a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's going on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing your `clear:both` with a `float: none` should be enough to let `margin: auto` do the work.

Comment: As soon as I add float:none, my width becomes 100% instead of the 215px in the css

Comment: I fixed the problem! I still had display:inline istead of display:block, thanks @antoine!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="data-column"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.data {
    position: relative;
    width:90%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.data-column {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 215px;

    /* horizontal centering */
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;

    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;

    /* vertically centering */        
    top: 0;
    margin-top: auto;

    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;

    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/npyn8030/2/)